# Change render mode of an existing (vector tile) layer

Tags: openlayers

I have a situation where in most cases I need to draw a small hundred-ful of features on a map in a VectorTile (eg. municipalities). This layer switches between various modes of jurisdiction, with most of them being similar in characteristics to the municipality-one, so ~same performance implications. I've set the rendermode to 'vector' because this offers crisp features and has acceptable performance in this case. However, there's one mode where the features to draw are in significantly greater number (around 200 000, rather than ~500). For this case, the 'hybrid' (or 'image', but that's getting removed in 6.6) render mode is more suitable because it performs better.

I'd like to switch between the 'vector' and 'hybrid' depending on the mode this layer is put in. Is there a way to change a layer's renderer outside of its constructor? There appears not to be a 'setRenderMode' method. Can I set the layer's renderer in some other way so I can dynamically switch between render modes within the same layer? I'm okay with this being a hack because unfortunately a grand refactoring to separate out layers for each mode is not in the cards right now.

TL;DR: Is it possible to, effectively, change the render mode in an existing layer?

Answer (score 0):

Well this turned out to be a lot simpler than I had imagined. The VectorTile implementation stores the `renderMode` value in `renderMode_`, and the renderer is not initialized when the layer is initialized, rather it is selected when a render is necessary. Therefore changing `renderMode_` into the desired value does the trick.

```java
this.layer.renderMode_ = isBadlyPerformingMode() ? "hybrid" : "vector";
this.layer.changed();
```